# Has it been proven that causality means the S-matrix is analytic?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, causality, s-matrix-theory, analyticity

In books like 'the analytic S-matrix' they give justification that causality implies analyticity however they also said it hasn't been explicitly proven.

This book was written a while ago, has it been proven yet?